# CSS Stylesheets in Graphviz

Tags: css, graphviz

Graphviz supports CSS stylesheets for SVG ouptut. There's an attribute [`stylesheet`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/stylesheet/) in the documentation.

Should the attribute `stylesheet` be given separately to all the nodes? How can I set a stylesheet for all the graph elements just writing the CSS filename to one place only? Where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute `stylesheet` is given to a graph definition. See the sample below.

sample.dot

```
graph sample {
    stylesheet="sample.css"
    a [class="sky"]
    b [class="ground"]
    a -- b
}
```

sample.css

```
.sky>ellipse {
    fill: deepskyblue;
}

.ground>ellipse {
    fill: palegreen;
}
```

command

```
dot -Tsvg < sample.dot > sample.svg
```

sample.svg

[image]